# Calculate correct unit vectors for a Local Coordinate System

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, computer-science, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to implement unit vectors for a local coordinate system (LCS) based on a reference black-box implementation. In my result, I get the three unit vectors U, V, and W. The vectors are correct, but their orientation different from the referece black-box implementation.

- Input:
  3-points that define the LCS. An origin, a point on the Z-axis, and a point along the XZ-plane. All given with reference to the global coordinates.

For example, for following LCS:

```
origin=(45.795510, -28.358400, 1.294882)
zPoint=(45.791520, -28.351800, 1.394584)
xzPoint=(45.846980, -28.443800, 1.302594)
```

Based on this I calculate the following U, V, W vectors:

```
U => (-0.039900, 0.066000, 0.997022)
V => (0.514653, -0.853923, 0.077123) 
W => (0.856469, 0.516198, 0.000104)
```

My calculation:

```
U = normalize( subtract(zPoint, origin) )
W = normalize( U x subtract(xzPoint, origin) )
V = normalize( W x U )
```

*normalize, subtract, and x (cross-product) are same as standard vector operations.*

The reference black-box implementation yields the following for the same input:

```
U => ( 0.514653, -0.853922, 0.077123) # V in my implementation
V => ( 0.856469,  0.516197, 0.000104) # W in my implementation
W => (-0.039900,  0.066000, 0.997021) # U in my implementation
```

- The problem: My implementation matches the reference in almost all cases except for the LCS above. I can't figure out what's incorrect, or if there's something missing in the input that's needed to orient these unit vectors in the right direction

Please excuse my limited math skills. Thanks a lot for all your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, the LCS has unit vectors in the directions of the positive $X,$ $Y,$ and $Z$ axes. Let's call those unit vectors $\hat x,$ $\hat y,$ and $\hat z$ respectively.

Now `zPoint` is a point on the $Z$ axis of the LCS; presumably it is on the **positive** $Z$ axis, otherwise you cannot know which way the $Z$ axis goes.
Then `subtract(zPoint, origin)` presumably subtracts the coordinates of `origin` from the coordinates of `zPoint` to give you the coordinates of a vector pointing from `origin` to `zPoint`, that is, in the positive $Z$ direction.
Then `normalize( subtract(zPoint, origin) )` makes that into a unit vector
in the positive $Z$ direction, namely, $\hat z.$
So your first line of code sets `U` to $\hat z.$

Similarly, `subtract(xzPoint, origin)` gives you a vector $v$ from `origin` to `xzPoint`. Since `xzPoint` is a point in the $X,Z$ plane of the LCS,
the vector $v$ must be $a\hat x + b\hat z$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b.$
Since you set `U` to $\hat z$, `U x subtract(xzPoint, origin)` is
$$
\hat z \times v = \hat z \times (a\hat x + b\hat z) = a \hat z\times \hat x = a\hat y.
$$
Then `normalize( U x subtract(xzPoint, origin) )` will return $\hat y$ if $a > 0$ and
$-\hat y$ if $a < 0.$ What it does if $a = 0$ is up to the function designer; it could return $0$, throw an exception, or something else. But $0\hat y = 0$ and there is no way to reliably "normalize" the zero vector to the unit $Y$ vector of your arbitrary LCS, so we had better not have $a = 0.$

So the second line of code will produce $\hat y$ in the happy circumstances where `xzPoint` is in the $X,Z$ plane and on the positive-$X$ side of the $Z$ axis. If we are given a point on the other side of the $Z$ axis we get a vector in the opposite direction from $\hat y$ and if `xzPoint` is on the $Z$ axis (which is part of the $X,Z$ plane) then we don't get an axis vector at all.
But whatever you get from the second line, you set `W` to it.

Assuming we were given a "happy" choice of `xzPoint`, we now have `U` set to $\hat z$ and `W` set to $\hat y.$
Then the third line computes
$$\hat y \times \hat z = \hat x.$$
Note that in the absence of numerical error, this equation is exactly correct;
the cross product of two orthogonal unit vectors is a unit vector.
But you might have some numerical error in the calculations of `W` (aka $\hat y$)
and `U` (aka $\hat z$), so you normalize the result of the cross product in order to have a more accurate value of $\hat x.$ You then set `V` to $\hat x$ in the third line of code.

So now you have:

- `V` set to $\hat x.$
- `W` set to $\hat y.$
- `U` set to $\hat z.$

The reference implementation, on the other hand,
sets `U` to $\hat x,$ `V` to $\hat y,$ and `W` to $\hat z,$
which we might expect since this preserves the alphabetical order of the vectors relative to the axes.

The main discrepancy is how you named your vectors `U`, `V`, `W`.
If you want to match the reference implementation, you want `W` to be $\hat z,$ so your first line of code should set `W`, not `U`, and so forth.
I also see some differences in the sixth decimal place, possibly due to different algorithms with different numerical errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination. I adjusted the U, V, W directions to satisfy the oritentations in the reference implementation. That's actually the part of the answer I seek.

If these equations are correct atleast, then is it possible for U to be anything other than x?

Comment: The description of the input data is not clear about whether `xzPoint` will always be in the part of the $X,Z$ plane such that your second line of code produces $\hat y.$ If `xzPoint` could be anywhere in the plane except on the $Z$ axis, you could end up with $-\hat y$ instead, and when that happens you will end up computing $-\hat x$ on the third line. There are also possible numerical roundoff errors throughout the calculations that could result in something not exactly agreeing with the original $\hat x$ vector. No other obvious sources of error occur to me.

Comment: Thanks. The point would always be on the positive xzPlane (at least as per input specs). I think it can be on the zAxis only (but I'd need to verfiy).